# HTTP Cache with Request Authorization

Tags: http, caching, authorization, varnish, http-caching

Do any standards for interaction between HTTP cache and request authorization exist?

Let's imagine the case: different urls of a site are protected by a role-based authorization system. How to combine caching of content with authorization of requests? Is there any RFC-asserted approach?

1. [FoS](http://foshttpcache.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user-context.html#alternative-for-paywalls-authorization-request) describes the approach when Proxy Cache sends HEAD requests to called GET urls to check accessibility. It seems like the way that doesn't conflict with HTTP RFCs. In [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) HEAD purpose:

> This method can be used for obtaining
> metadata about the selected representation without transferring the
> representation data and is often used for testing hypertext links for
> validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

It seems quite effective but description is incomplete. According to RFC   server [should send](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.2) `Cache-Control: no-cache` to prevent caching by other caches from a chain.
That architecture looks like coupled - it is non-RFC behavior and so it should be configured manually.

2. On other hand seems like the problem could be solved with `Cache-Control: no-cache` directive and Conditional Requests [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232). This approach is not so effective like the previous one: preconditions should be validated every time. The main advantage that it should work out of box with current proxy engines. I didn't find significant contradictions with RFC but IMO Conditional Requests are not designed for a request authorization.
3. Some hacks could be applied also. Does HTTP define mechanics for such cases? Or at least wide-spread practices?

Answer (score 1):

By default in Varnish only GET and HEAD requests without a “Cookie”- or an “Authorization”-Header are cached. This is baked into the default VCL. On Ubuntu: /etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
# sub vcl_recv {
#     ...
#     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
#         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
#         /* Not cacheable by default */
#         return (pass);
#     }
#     return (lookup);
# }
```